# $G$ is a nonabelian finite group, then $|Z(G)|\leq \frac{1}{4}|G|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If $G$ is a nonabelian finite group, then I have to show that $|Z(G)|\leq\frac{1}{4}|G|$, where $|Z(G)|$ denotes the center of group.

I have got this question through random search on net. I am finding it difficult to solve. Moreover, I am not sure whether is it true or not.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint: If $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian.

Comment: How can I apply this result here?

Comment: Supose $\,|Z(G)|>\frac{|G|}{4}\,$ , then what fraction of the order of $\,G\,$ can the center's order be? Then what can you say about the quotient $\,G/Z(G)\,$ ? This is a good hint. +1